# Where mistake in sql LIKE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I try to count all items from another table with this select:

```
SELECT id, name,  (SELECT count(*) 
                   FROM prekes_main 
                   WHERE prekes_main.pristKaina = 1 
                   and   prekes_main.pg_kodas LIKE 'grupes_main.pg_kodas%') as pristKaina
FROM grupes_main 
WHERE grupes_main.level = 1 
and grupes_main.name <> ''
```

In LIKE clause I want automatically get selected grupes_main column pg_kodas, but in this query it always returns 0, where is mistake in LIKE function? thx

Comment: How the data looks like?

Comment: don't put this sub query in the select statement... you're going to ask for a count each time there is a record matching your where clause ! Plus there's no join between the 2 groups of datas. You should revise your logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  id, name,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    prekes_main
        WHERE   prekes_main.pristKaina = 1
                AND prekes_main.pg_kodas LIKE CONCAT(grupes_main.pg_kodas, '%')
        ) pristKaina
FROM    grupes_main
WHERE   grupes_main.level = 1
        AND grupes_main.name <> ''
```